# cordova-plugin-console doesn't support this project's cordova-ios version

Tags: ios, ionic-framework, ionic3, cordova-plugins

I have upgraded my environment from ionic 1 to ionic 3.19.1. However, my project is still ionic v1 (or if im not mistaken below v1, not sure)

I ran the command

```
ionic cordova build ios --v1
```

and there is this failure.

```
Discovered plugin "cordova-plugin-console" in config.xml. Adding it to the project
Installing "cordova-plugin-console" for ios
Plugin doesn't support this project's cordova-ios version. cordova-ios: 4.5.4, failed version requirement: <4.5.0
Skipping 'cordova-plugin-console' for ios
```

what does it mean and how to resolve it?

My environment is below:

```
ionic version 3.19.1
cordova version 8.0.0
npm version 5.6.0
macos High Sierra 10.13.1
xcode 9.2
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You simply need to uninstall `cordova-plugin-console`.
Check cordova-ios 4.5.0 release [here](https://cordova.apache.org/announcements/2017/09/08/ios-release.html).

> **Important!** If you have included cordova-plugin-console in your project, you must remove it, otherwise your project will not build.

It is now integrated into cordova-ios platform(4.5.0 onwards).

Your current version is cordova-ios: 4.5.4 according to the error message.

Here is the issue tracker of [integration](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/CB-13164) into cordova-ios.

Do:

```
ionic cordova plugin remove cordova-plugin-console
```

Comment: This is cool for iOS, but what about Android?

Comment: @DARKGuy The plugin was not [meant for android](https://www.npmjs.com/package/cordova-plugin-console#description) and was deprecated.

Comment: Yeah that's obvious, that's why I was asking what options do we have in Android

Comment: @DARKGuy you mean something like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/52782751/4826457)? It's not clear what you want to achieve?

Comment: Yeah exactly, something like that, but it doesn't work in Release mode, only in Debug builds

Comment: @DARKGuy enabling console logs in release is probably not a good idea. You might want to look for a logging/crash reporting service....