# Display Cordova "console.log" entries in Android Studio

Tags: android, cordova, android-studio, vue.js, console.log

I have a Cordova app using Vue.js, and lots of logging using the standard Javascript/browser console.log(). Up until now I've only been targeting iOS, and those console.log messages appear in the xCode log viewer.

Now, however, I'm also targeting Android. I've successfully imported the Cordova project into Android Studio and the app is running in debug mode in the Emulator. But, I can't find the console.log output anywhere.

I think the log output should appear here, but there is nothing from my app at all.

[image]

I've also tried Logcat, as @Lukasz describes, which also had no effect:

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I finally resolved this. I had to enable Developer Options in settings and enable USB Debugging.

Answer (score 6):

You should try to use chrome inspect as described here:

https://developers.google.com/web/tools/chrome-devtools/remote-debugging/

If you really want to see the console.log statements from inside the Android Studio you can use logcat View -> Tool Windows -> Logcat. Remember to filter it by 'CONSOLE' statement like I did on the image below.

[image]

Comment: I've done that, but with no effect. See updated question above for an image.

Comment: Regarding the Chrome solution you linked to, does this also work when using the Android Studio emulator?

Comment: Yes it should, if your app is debuggable it should work. Have a look here: https://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/latest/guide/next/#chrome-remote-debugging. Also, I am not sure why the logcat isn't showing anything for you, does it show anything when you clear the filter?

Answer (score 1):

If you're not seeing console.log in LogCat, ensure your application is debuggable. This will be true for apps run from Android Studio (I think) but if you're debugging a 3rd party APK like I am, it won't. Maybe this will save someone the 3 hours I wasted on it.

So ensure `android:debuggable="true"` is there in the `application` tag of of your AndroidManifest.xml file