# how to capture native cordova exceptions and console.logs and save them to txt?

Tags: android, ios, cordova, plugins

I need to save the various console.logs implemented in the code in a txt file so as to keep track in case of errors. I read that you could use the “cordova-plugin-console” plugin but I can't use it. Could someone tell me how to implement it?
It is an app that uses the Cordova framework to create apps for Android and iOS.

Thank you in advance.

I tried to install the plugin with the following command: `cordova plugin add cordova-plugin-console`
and I created a js file inside the www folder with the following code:

```
var fs = cordova.file;


function logToTextFile(message) {
    var logMessage = message + '\n';

   
    window.requestFileSystem(LocalFileSystem.PERSISTENT, 0, function (fileSystem) {
        fileSystem.root.getFile("app_logs.txt", { create: true, exclusive: false }, function (fileEntry) {
            fileEntry.createWriter(function (fileWriter) {
                fileWriter.seek(fileWriter.length); 
                fileWriter.write(logMessage);
            }, function (error) {
                console.error("Errore nella scrittura del file: " + JSON.stringify(error));
            });
        }, function (error) {
            console.error("Errore nell'apertura del file: " + JSON.stringify(error));
        });
    }, function (error) {
        console.error("Errore nella richiesta del file system: " + JSON.stringify(error));
    });
}


console.log = function(message) {
    logToTextFile(message);
    
    originalConsoleLog(message);
}


function originalConsoleLog(message) {
    if (window.console && typeof window.console.log === "function") {
        window.console.log(message);
    }
}
```

and in the index.html I added:

```
<script src="./log.js"></script>
```

but it doesn't work, can anyone help me solve it?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Display Cordova "console.log" entries in Android Studio](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52782751/display-cordova-console-log-entries-in-android-studio)

Comment: Does this answer your question? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8264645/how-to-save-logcat-contents-to-file